# Postgres - how to format a date array column

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I query my `test_table` I get back the following rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_table;
```

```
id    event_dates_array
1     {'2012-01-01', '2013-01-01'}
2     {'2015-01-01', '2016-01-01'}
```

The `event_dates_array` is a `date array` column.

I want the query to return the `event_dates_array` formatted so that the date arrays only show the years, like so:

```
id    event_dates_array
1     {'2012', '2013'}
2     {'2015', '2016'}
```

You can do this with normal date columns like so: `date_part('year', event_dates)`

But how do you do it for date array columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `JOIN LATERAL` to access each date in the array and aggregate each `date_part`:

```
WITH data(id, event_dates_array) AS (
    VALUES ('1', ARRAY ['2012-01-01', '2013-01-01']::date[])
         , ('2', ARRAY ['2015-01-01', '2016-01-01']::date[])
)
SELECT id, event_years
FROM data
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT array_agg(date_part('year', date)::int) AS event_years
    FROM unnest(event_dates_array) AS date
) AS f
```

returns

```
+--+-----------+
|id|event_years|
+--+-----------+
|1 |{2012,2013}|
|2 |{2015,2016}|
+--+-----------+
```

Comment: You can use `cross join` instead of `join` and then remove the `on` clause.

Answer (score 1):

If all date literals has the month and day portion as `-01-01`, then using

```
SELECT id, REPLACE(event_dates_array, '-01', '') AS event_years_array
  FROM test_table;

id  event_years_array
1   {'2012', '2013'}
2   {'2015', '2016'}
```

will be enough.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=08502d29058717e8d82126f27ad326b5)</kbd>