# how to create the table in postgrest in datetype date in single variable?

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE customer_details 
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id VARCHAR(40), 
    invoice_number VARCHAR(40),
    invoice_date DATE NOT NULL,
    due_date  DATE NOT NULL,
    start_date DATE NOT NULL,
    end_date DATE NOT NULL,
    bill_period  DATE, DATE
);
```

Someone, please help me?

```
Customer ID CSD003456021
Invoice Number TPFLINV0011121
Invoice Date 18th November 2021
Due Date 23rd November 2021
Bill Period 1st Oct 2021 to 15th Oct 2021
```

how to create the table and how to write the select the table?

Like

```
select * 
from customer_details;
```

How to represent two dates in a single column like Bill Period?

Comment: Postgres does not have a datatype that represents a date/time range. The closest thing is `interval`, but that is a *duration*, not a specific bracket of time.

Comment: You *could* use a date array column.  Some [example usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64115746/postgres-how-to-format-a-date-array-column)

Comment: Thanks INSERT INTO customer_details (id , customer_id, invoice_number, invoice_date, due_date, start_date, end_date, bill_period)
VALUES (102, 'CX009042031', 'ETPLINV0011321', '8 November 2021', '24 November 2021', ' 1 Oct 2021',  '15 Oct 2021', ARRAY ['1 Oct 2021', '15 Oct 2021']::date[]);

Comment: ERROR:  column "bill_period" is of type date but expression is of type date[]
LINE 2: ...24 November 2021', ' 1 Oct 2021',  '15 Oct 2021', ARRAY ['1 ...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
SQL state: 42804
Character: 240

Comment: what do to: i add type case -> ARRAY ['1 Oct 2021', '15 Oct 2021']::bill_period::date[] ->like that, but i got error :bill_period doest not exits

Answer (score 0):

I changed the datatype

```
ALTER TABLE customer_details ALTER COLUMN bill_period TYPE  VARCHAR;
```

After that Insert that value

```
INSERT INTO customer_details (id , customer_id, invoice_number, invoice_date, due_date, start_date, end_date, bill_period)
VALUES (102, 'CX009042031', 'ETPLINV0011321', '8 November 2021', '24 November 2021', ' 1 Oct 2021',  '15 Oct 2021', ARRAY ['1 Oct 2021', '15 Oct 2021']::date[]);
```

output

```
{2021-10-01,2021-10-15}
```